# Why are some of my grid columns stacking?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'd like to order my bootstrap cards thus:
[image]

My code is this:

```
<div class="row ">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6 mb-1" style="height: 75vh;">
    <div class="map svelte-xu5vn1" id="map">
      ...
    </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
    <div class="col-6">
      <a rel="prefetch" href="communes/xxx/objects/Cykelhus">
        <div class="card  mr-1 mb-1">
          <div class="card-body text-center">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="img/300x300/cykelhus.thumb.jpg" alt="(image)">  
            <p class="card-text">Cykelhus</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
       <a rel="prefetch" href="communes/brf_masthugget/objects/Sedumtak">
         <div class="card  mr-1 mb-1">
         ... as per the above
```

But I get this result:
[image]

What do I need to change?

Comment: Your `.col-6` are not in a `.row` which is the flex container for the columns. Else they are just regular display block divs that will stack on top of each other

Comment: Just saw this after posting my answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, I needed to add a `<div class="row">` before the first of the cards:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <a rel="prefetch" href="communes/xxx/objects/Cykelhus">
    ...
```

And close it of course.

hmm, sure I'd already tried that ...